# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Links whitelisted error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to use Firebase Dynamic Link in Flutter. In my application I have classes and each class has a code, a firebase dynamic links creates a link while the teacher creates the class. But when creating it gives this error and gives up.

```
FirebaseException ([firebase_dynamic_links/unknown] com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException:
 400: We could not match param 'https://com.example.app?ref=7349558834'
 with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project.
[https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429
[https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429])
```

How can I fix this error?

This is the link I want to create: https://com.example.app?ref=7349558834

The code I wrote to create the link

```
import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';


class DynamicLinkProvider {
Future<String> createLink(String refCode) async {
    final String url = "https://com.example.app?ref=$refCode";

    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      link: Uri.parse(url),
      uriPrefix: "https://exampleapp.page.link/",
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
          packageName: "com.example.app", minimumVersion: 0),
    );
    final dynamicLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(dynamicLinkParams);

    return dynamicLink.shortUrl.toString();
  }
}
```

Urls I added to Allowlist Url Pattern in Firebase Dynamic Link:

^https{0,1}://google.com([/#?].*){0,1}$

^https://.*.com/.*$

https://www.example.com/

^https://mybrand.com/.*$

https://com.example.app?ref=

https://com.example.app?ref=.*$

https://com.example.app?ref=/.*$

https://com.example.app?ref=*

https://example.app.page.link/*

https://com..example.app

https://example.app.page.link/$

https://com.example.app?ref=$

^https://com.example.app?ref=*$

**https://com.example.app?ref=7349558834** what else can I add to create such a link?